# Flask Limiter 127.0.0.1 IP

Tags: python, angularjs, nginx, flask

I'm using Flask Limiter to block flood requests.. However when I use flask_limiter.util.get_remote_address.. It always returns 127.0.0.1 on my pool.. I'm using AngularJS as a front-end, flask as my back-end and Nginx as my server. Both my front-end and back-end is on one machine in my AWS..  So I'm trying to test it via numerous failed attemtps and then on my pool of remote addresses it only shows 127.0.0.1..

These are my request headers:

```
Authorization: 
Referer: example.com
Origin: example.com
Content-Length: 36
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Connection: close
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

I tried printing request.headers.environ and this is what I got:

```
{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': '', 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://example.com/', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/0.10.4', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'PATH_INFO': '/user/login/dp', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://example.com', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'werkzeug.server.shutdown': <function shutdown_server at 0x7f5017896398>, 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '36', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close', 'SERVER_NAME': '0.0.0.0', 'REMOTE_PORT': 52173, 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 'werkzeug.request': <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/dp' [POST]>, 'wsgi.input': <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f50178938d0>, 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f50198671e0>, 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate'}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you setting the x-forwarded-for header in your remote proxy? If so, use `flask_limiter.util.get_ipaddr`.

Comment: will try this one thanks

Comment: No problem.  You basically have to let the application know that the request is being sent through a reverse proxy and that the remote user isn't the intermediary layer.

Comment: Does this also happen in Apache? I'm guessing that this proxy thing is because of Nginx

Comment: It's possible that it will happen with any major reverse proxy.  You simply need to make sure that a header is being set that will give reverse-proxied applications the original source of the user.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You can set x-forwarded-for to your Nginx setting:
Open this file:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf
Add:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Under your server name. Don't forget to restart Nginx.